# Why "if InputText == '0' || isempty(InputText)" in MATLAB is giving error?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, conditional-statements, logical-operators, logical-or

`if InputText == '0' || isempty(InputText)`

in MATLAB is giving error:

Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

I'm looking for an explanation for it. Isn't `InputText == '0'` returning a logical value nor the other? Definitely the second is, so what's the problem with `InputText == '0'`?

I have a MATLAB script and I want to ask user finish a procedure by either entering a '0' or just pressing space in it; here is the code:

```
if InputText == '0' || isempty(InputText)
    break
end
```

and here is the error I get consequently:

Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Error in test (line 11)
if InputText == '0' || isempty(InputText)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `InputText = '012'` then you can see what your first check outputs:

```
InputText == '0'
>> 
 ans = [true, false, false]
```

The single quotes indicate a [character array](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html), and it is treated similarly to numeric arrays for comparisons, so the output of the `== '0'` operation is a comparison of each element with `'0'`. This means the output is nonscalar, so you can't use it with `&&` or `||`.

If you want to check *"is the whole character array `InputText` equivalent to `'0'`?"* then you should use [`strcmp`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html)

So your condition would be

```
if strcmp(InputText, '0') || isempty(InputText)
    break
end
```

Comment: gotcha! Switching from single quote to double quote worked for me fine. now I can figure out what is the difference between these two! Thanks.

Comment: Docs for [characters and strings](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html). Characters are the original data type for text, and have broader function compatibility generally because all of the old built-ins work with them. But newer versions of MATLAB are increasingly using the additional functionality of strings